# Javars Comparison of Complex Object Graph

Tags: java, javers, object-comparison

Not sure how to approach the comparison using Javers for the below example

```
class Step { 
 String stepPropertyA
 Int stepPropertyB
}

class Procedure {
 String procedurePropertyA
 int procedurePropertyB
 list<Step> steps
}

class Solution {
  String solutionPropertyA
  int solutionPropertyB
  list<Procedures> procedures
}

Diff = javers.comapre(solution1, solution2)
```

Do I need to use CustomPropertyComparator for this.. if so do I need to use multiple CustomPropertyComparator for each list of different type ?